# How can I edit table properties in tabular model in visual studio?

Tags: ssas-tabular

I want to add new columns in two tables in a tabular model. But I faced three questions in the process.

1. When I opened the table properties, I found here has filter rows commands.  I tried to directly delete filter rows command here, but I clicked validate, it shows the credentials for this operation could not be validated. How can I renew the SQL statement?
2. When I open design and click import. Error appears: Cannot import the partition query because the set of columns in the partition definition does not match those in the table definition. The following required columns are mission.
   The partition only sets the datetime, I do not understand what the error is here.
3. When I opened design in the table properties and click update, the error: cannot save changes because the partitions' schema has been changed. Please correct the schema and try again. But the table does not have any partitions. How can I fix it?